# sed + fix PATH syntax with sed

Tags: sed

Sometime we have problem with the file PATH syntax

For example

Wrong PATH as (double back slash)

```
     /etc//sysconfig/network
```

While the right syntax is

```
   /etc/sysconfig/network
```

How to fix by sed if the PATH have two double spaces (consecutive)

For example

```
    echo   /etc//sysconfig/network | sed …
```

will print

```
    /etc/sysconfig/network
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use the  shell(bash)

```
$ path="/etc//sysconfig/network"
$ echo ${path//\/\//\/}
/etc/sysconfig/network
```

otherwise, if you still prefer sed

```
$ echo "$path" | sed 's/\/\//\//g'
/etc/sysconfig/network
```

Comment: what's the result of `/etc///sysconfig/network`? :) +1 for bash version

Comment: if OP has that kind of data, then something is wrong during his/her string concatenation code. If such a thing should happen, then use the wildcard.

Comment: Yeah, in all fairness, that wasn't in the original spec.

Answer (score 2):

The following looks like a sine wave but it does the trick:

```
pax> echo /etc//sysconfig/network | sed 's/\/\/*/\//g'
/etc/sysconfig/network
```

It works by collapsing all occurrences of two or more `/` characters into a single one.